# Change background color on homeAsUpIndicator

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I'm trying to change the light blue background colour on the `homeAsUpIndicator` in my `ActionBarSherlock`. I have found plenty of answers telling me how to change the white arrow but none telling me how to change the background colour.

[image]

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `actionBarItemBackground` theme attribute.